# SSRS 2016 Report Rendering Error

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportmanager

I'm currently using a local instance of SSRS 2016. I've noticed that when I deploy a project and access the reports via Report Manager those with shared data sets will not render, instead I am met with an error message as below.

> "An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
>   The permissions granted to user 'Sam\Samuel' are insufficient for
>   performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied)"

I'm sure the problem has something to do with shared data sets as reports in the same project will open fine so long as the data set they're using is embedded and thus not shared.

Any advice as to why this is might be happening would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: the error message is clear `The permissions granted to user 'Sam\Samuel' are insufficient for performing this operation.`..did you tried granting permissions

Comment: I had granted Browser, Content Manager, My Reports and Publisher permissions to the user 'Sam\Samuel' in the security tab of both the report and the individual shared dataset. Is there somewhere else I might need to change them?

Comment: Does he has database access

Comment: Well my data source uses SQL Server authentication with the SA credentials stored in Report Manager. If this is the case then I believed the user wouldn't need database access? Though they do through Windows authentication, I'm just not using it.

Comment: Can you try giving user permisissions?

Comment: It doesn't seem to help. I'm at a loss as to what's causing this.